# MacVim command + $KEY shortcuts & behavior in GVIM under Ubuntu

Tags: vim, macvim

I have been using MacVim & have gotten used to it but my main development computers are all Linux(Ubuntu)

I'd like MacVim like shortcuts and behavior

I know you can get windows like behavior like so

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin
```

how can I get Mac like behavior in GVIM on ubuntu?

Comment: MacVim key bindings are set with this file: https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/blob/master/src/MacVim/gvimrc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use MacVim on Mac OS X at work, GVim on Linux at home and CLI Vim everywhere. What do you call "MacVim like shortcuts and behavior"?

Do you mean "standard OS-wide shortcuts" like <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>light/left arrow</kbd>? I don't know of any features MacVim has that GVim hasn't beside a very elegant and impressive level of OS integration.

Shortcuts that use the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> key are obviously not supported because there is no <kbd>Cmd</kbd> key on a typical PC keyboard. If you really want to have them you will need to explicitly add them to your `~/.gvimrc` with another modifier key. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>right/left arrow</kbd> and other basic Mac OS X text-editing shortcuts must also be explicitly added to your `~/.gvimrc`. You'll quickly find limitations in this strategy.

Hell, GVim doesn't even really support Gnome's own default shortcuts anyway.

That's the wrong approach.

Vim's own commands, motions, text-objects and the grammar that ties them are a lot more efficient and portable. You should focus on that instead.

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> = `:e <Tab>`
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>right arrow</kbd> = `$` for positioning the cursor or `A` to insert text
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>left arrow</kbd> = `^` or `0` (`0` is "first column', `^` is "first printable character") for positioning the cursor or `I` to insert text
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>right arrow</kbd> = `e` or `E` or `w` or `W`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>left arrow</kbd> = `b` or `B`
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>right arrow</kbd> = `v$`
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>left arrow</kbd> = `v^`
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>right arrow</kbd> = `ve` then `eee` as many times as necessary or `v2e`

and so on…

Like I've said before, read `:help motion.txt`, it will blow your mind.

Comment: I meant like the hotkeys, cmd key was my windows key.

Comment: What are "hotkeys"? `<D-...>` works only in MacVim on Mac OS X: it doesn't mean anything to Vim outside of this context and the "Windows/Super" key is not even registered by GVim on Linux. That's two possible modifiers out: time to reconsider your idea.